# Postifx and Dovecot: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, saslauthd

When I sent an test mail from my Gmail to my server, I get this error:

**fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms**

Here is all my configuration files and log files, to help us:

**/var/log/maillog**

```
Nov  4 14:42:49 ns1 postfix/postfix-script[2147]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Nov  4 14:42:49 ns1 postfix/master[1340]: terminating on signal 15
Nov  4 14:42:49 ns1 postfix/postfix-script[2228]: starting the Postfix mail system
Nov  4 14:42:49 ns1 postfix/master[2230]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Nov  4 14:45:37 ns1 postfix/smtpd[2314]: connect from mail-oi0-f51.google.com[209.85.218.51]
Nov  4 14:45:37 ns1 postfix/smtpd[2314]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Nov  4 14:45:38 ns1 postfix/master[2230]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 2314 exit status 1
Nov  4 14:45:38 ns1 postfix/master[2230]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Nov  4 14:47:18 ns1 postfix/anvil[2317]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:209.85.218.51) at Nov  4 14:45:37
Nov  4 14:47:18 ns1 postfix/anvil[2317]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:209.85.218.51) at Nov  4 14:45:37
Nov  4 14:47:18 ns1 postfix/anvil[2317]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Nov  4 14:45:37
```

**systemctl status dovecot -l**

```
[root@ns1 ~]# systemctl status dovecot -l
   dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-11-04 14:43:28 BRST; 35s ago
  Process: 2246 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/dovecot/prestartscript (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2250 (dovecot)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dovecot.service
           ├─2250 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F
           ├─2251 dovecot/anvil
           ├─2252 dovecot/log
           └─2254 dovecot/config

Nov 04 14:43:28 ns1.domain.com.br systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
Nov 04 14:43:28 ns1.domain.com.br systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
```

**systemctl status postfix -l**

```
[root@ns1 ~]# systemctl status postfix -l
   postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-11-04 14:42:49 BRST; 1min 55s ago
  Process: 2141 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2158 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2154 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2152 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2230 (master)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─2230 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
           ├─2231 pickup -l -t unix -u
           └─2232 qmgr -l -t unix -u

Nov 04 14:42:49 ns1.domain.com.br systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
Nov 04 14:42:49 ns1.domain.com.br postfix/postfix-script[2228]: starting the Postfix mail system
Nov 04 14:42:49 ns1.domain.com.br postfix/master[2230]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Nov 04 14:42:49 ns1.domain.com.br systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
```

**systemctl status saslauthd -l**

```
[root@ns1 ~]# systemctl status saslauthd -l
   saslauthd.service - SASL authentication daemon.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/saslauthd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-11-03 12:19:08 BRST; 1 day 2h ago
  Process: 1978 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/saslauthd -m $SOCKETDIR -a $MECH $FLAGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1979 (saslauthd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/saslauthd.service
           ├─1979 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /run/saslauthd -a pam -r
           ├─1980 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /run/saslauthd -a pam -r
           ├─1981 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /run/saslauthd -a pam -r
           ├─1982 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /run/saslauthd -a pam -r
           └─1983 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /run/saslauthd -a pam -r

Nov 03 12:19:08 ns1.domain.com.br systemd[1]: Starting SASL authentication daemon....
Nov 03 12:19:08 ns1.domain.com.br saslauthd[1979]: detach_tty      : master pid is: 1979
Nov 03 12:19:08 ns1.domain.com.br saslauthd[1979]: ipc_init        : listening on socket: /run/saslauthd/mux
Nov 03 12:19:08 ns1.domain.com.br systemd[1]: Started SASL authentication daemon..
```

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
# MY CONFIGS
myhostname = mail.domain.com.br
mydomain = domain.com.br
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, ns1.domain.com.br
mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
relay_domains = $mydestination
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891

# SASL
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = domain.com.br
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:/var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket

# TLS
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/mail.domain.com.br.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/mail.domain.com.br.crt
smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
```

**/etc/postfix/master.cf**

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

**/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf**

```
protocols = imap pop3
listen = *
```

**/etc/dovecot/10-auth.conf**

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth_mechanisms = plain login
```

**/etc/dovecot/10-master.conf**

```
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    #mode = 0660
    #user = postfix
    #group = postfix
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }

  # Auth process is run as this user.
  #user = $default_internal_user
}
```

Thanks for the atention.

**@UPDATE 01**

**Here is the log file:**

```
Nov  6 11:02:35 ns1 postfix/smtpd[3950]: connect from mail-oi0-f47.google.com[209.85.218.47]
Nov  6 11:02:35 ns1 postfix/smtpd[3950]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Nov  6 11:02:36 ns1 postfix/master[12735]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd pid 3950 exit status 1
Nov  6 11:02:36 ns1 postfix/master[12735]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Nov  6 11:04:16 ns1 postfix/anvil[3952]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:209.85.218.47) at Nov  6 11:02:35
Nov  6 11:04:16 ns1 postfix/anvil[3952]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:209.85.218.47) at Nov  6 11:02:35
Nov  6 11:04:16 ns1 postfix/anvil[3952]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Nov  6 11:02:35
```

**Here is the postconf -n**

```
[root@ns1 ~]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
mydomain = domain.com.br
myhostname = mail.domain.com.br
mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = domain.com.br
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service unix:/var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket permit_mynetworks permit_inet_interfaces
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/mail.domain.com.br.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/mail.domain.com.br.key
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_tls_cache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_exchange_name = /var/lib/postfix/prng_exch
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

**Here is the versions:**

postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64
dovecot-2.2.10-5.el7.x86_64
CentOS Linux 7.2.1511
Kernel Linux 4.8.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 on x86_64

**@UPDATE 02**

**Here is my doveconf -n:**

```
[root@ns1 ~]# doveconf -n
# 2.2.10: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 4.8.5-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core                                                                                                                                                             )
auth_mechanisms = plain login
disable_plaintext_auth = no
listen = *
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$mydestination` does not include your `$mydomain`. When Postfix receives mail, it looks up whether the domain is in `$mydestination`, if it isn't, it tries to authenticate the sender (as it thinks the mail is submitted by a client, not delivered by another server).

Add `$mydomain` or a list of domains hosted by the server to `$mydestination`.

Furthermore, your SASL configuration seems broken. You start `saslauthd`, but configure Postfix to interface Dovecot for authentication:

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
```

As you already configured Dovecot, you can omit using `saslauthd`. If mail submission fails, make sure `dovecot` is listed in `postconf -a`.

Comment: Now I have add the domain in $mydestination, and stopped the saslauthd service. And the dovecot is listed in postconf -a.

Comment: -- and is it working now, did anything change in the logs?

Comment: I will try again in next hour, because my MX records are not updated now...and the Gmail are not reaching my server because that...when I get the DNS updated I will let you know about the logs...thanks a lot!

Comment: Its not working...what else can be?

Comment: Please provide more details on your system: distribution, software versions, output of `postconf -n`, and log excerpts for the update configuration.

Comment: The main question is updated with the infos that you requested, thanks for your atention again

Comment: Please also provide the output of `doveconf -n` so that we can see the actual Dovecot configuration.

Comment: Updated again in @UPDATE 02, please I dont find any soluction for that yet...